# Do I need to uninstall RC1 before installing ASP.NET MVC 2.0 RC2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have an installation of ASP.NET MVC 2.0 RC1 which I am planning to upgrade to the newly released RC2.

This upgrade path isn't mentioned in the release notes. Does anyone know if I can upgrade from RC1 or should I uninstall it first?

I'd like to avoid any possible problems with the upgrade so if anyone has already done this and has any additional advise, comments or observations, your feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to bite the bullet and try a straight upgrade.

In doing so I was presented with the message:

> Component Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 has
>   failed to install with the following
>   error message: "A different version of
>   ASP.NET MVC 2 is already installed on
>   your system. Please uninstall this
>   version before proceeding with this
>   install."

It seems that, yes, you need to uninstall RC1 before installing RC2.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this with 2.0 but I did have to uninstall previous beta/rc versions in the older releases before upgrading to a new one.